# Can't add cookies to ajax page JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a simple JSP page with a div updated via AJAX XMLHttpRequest object
When I try to use (response.addCookies(String,String)) I get no errors but the page stops loading and there are no output whatsoever...
Are there no way I can add cookies through an Ajax request object???

Comment: Intuitively I would think adding cookies requires a page reload in the browser.

Comment: Thanks I figured that out after many and many tries and at last I decided to go with (session) instead of cookies....